# Skip values in case they are empty

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to skip values in case, they are empty. 
Data in my database looks similary:

```
gender : man
hair : blonde
eyes : blue
figure : slim


gender : woman
hair : blonde
eyes : blue
figure : slim
```

When I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE figure = 'slim' AND hair = 'blonde' AND eyes = '' AND gender = 'man';
```

It returns me nothing, because `eyes` is empty.
Data I get from form in PHP and empty data are fields, which user don't fill.

Can you help me, how can I fix it?
As driver for database I use PDO.

Comment: where field is not NULL ?

Comment: '' and NULL are not the same you should have **AND eyes is NULL**

Comment: OP means to entirely omit each field in the query which has not been supplied by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to step through the values one by one:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE "
$appender = "";
if ( !empty($gender) )
{
    $sql .= ( $appender . " gender = '" . $gender . "'");
    $appender = " AND ";
}
if ( !empty($hair) )
{
    $sql .= ( $appender . " hair= '" . $hair. "'");
    $appender = " AND ";
}
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

try this with IS NULL

```
   AND eyes is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses [**lazy binding**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) where the statement is dynamically generated, and the array built using `array_push`.

```
$params=array();
$sql ="SELECT * FROM people WHERE  1"
if (!empty($figure) ){
    $sql .=" AND figure =? ";
    array_push($params,$figure);
}
if (!empty($hair) ){
    $sql .=" AND figure =? ";
    array_push($params,$hair);
}if (!empty($eyes) ){
    $sql .=" AND figure =? ";
    array_push($params,$eyes);
}if (!empty($gender) ){
    $sql .=" AND figure =? ";
    array_push($params,$gender);
}
$stmt = $dbh->($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```